# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'server'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, visual-studio-code, chat

I'm making a python chat app for a school project based on code I found on a youtube video. I apologise if this seems rudimentary, but I'm still a beginner. The program consists of two files, a server.py file and a client.py file. So far, the server has run just fine, but the client.py file cannot run for the life of me. Every time I try to execute it, I am met with the following errors:

```
 line 87, in <module>
    client = Client()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'server'
```

Here's the code for the client.py:

```
from operator import truediv
import socket
import threading 
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog

class Client:

    def __init__(self, server):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.connect(('localhost', 1234))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False 
        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(targer=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(targer=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")
        
        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="Lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.end_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message =f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"


    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.server.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICKNAME':
                    self.server.send(self.nickname.encode('utd-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.server.close()
                break

    
client = Client()
```

My biggest issue is that 'server' is within the brackets of Client. Another issue is that for some reason, the last line doesn't seem to call the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Client's `init()` method by removing the `server` argument, it is **absolutely useless**, as inside the **constructor** the `server` variable gets declared & initialized without  the need of getting passed a server-instance from outside.

Thus, simply try:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self): # remove the argument after 'self'
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.connect(('localhost', 1234))
        #...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```py
#code before
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #other code
```

As even if something is going to be passed, it will be overwritten anyway.

The error you are getting is that the __init__() function expects an argument, server, but it is not getting it (argument self is automatic and does not need to be passed)

Or even better, with a default value that can be overridden, but if you dont pass a value, it will go to the default value.

```py
class Client:
    def __init__(self, server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)):
     
        #other code
```